# Problem with multirow and an image

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, tabularx, multirow

I am having trouble trying to make a tabularx table that contains a photo and has text at the other side of the page. Right now the photo overflows the text and is no longer being contained in the table.
I would like the table to include vertical spacing between lines to acomodate for the picture but right now I don't know how to do it

This is what it looks like:
[image: Current result]

This is the code that produces it:

```tex
\documentclass{resume}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{M{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|M{3cm}|Y|}
     \hline
            \multirow{4}{*}{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm, height=2.5cm]{image.jpg}}
            & \MakeUppercase{\huge\bf Name Goes Here} \\
            & (+34) 999 999 999 $\diamond$ mail@example.com \\ 
            & \href{example.com}{LinkedIn} · \href{example.com}{GitHub} \\ 
            & Someplace, Somewhere \\
     \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226225/problem-with-multirow-and-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `tabularray` package you will avoid to your problem.

**Edit:**
Its implementation of multi row cell, for it is used `\SetCell[r=<number>]{<cell formatting options>} <cell contents>` in the case, when its contents is higher than natural height of spanned rows in adjacent columns, doesn't protrude bottom of the cell but make it higher by adding vertical space to cells in spanned rows. This can be controlled by option `vspan`, which can be `default` (space is add to the bottom cell) or `even` (for details see package documentation: section *3.1 Table Specifications*).

This features of `tabularray` package gives *new possibilities* of handling such problems which are not covered by answers in the given link to duplicate (now six year old) question when `tabularray` did not yet exist.

```
\documentclass{article}%{resume} % since I haven't loaded resume document class
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[colorlinks, 
            urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z}, vlines,
               colspec={Q[c,m,wd=25mm] X[1, c,m]},
               rowsep = {1pt}
               row{1} = {font=\huge\bfseries, abovesep=5pt},
               }
\SetCell[r=4]{m} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
            & \MakeUppercase{Name Goes Here} \\
            & (+34) 999 999 999 $\diamond$ mail@example.com \\
            & \href{example.com}{LinkedIn} · \href{example.com}{GitHub} \\
            & Someplace, Somewhere \\
  \end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
In the case when natural size image has large height than width, the image will still stay inside of table. For example:

```
\SetCell[r=4]{m} \SetCell[r=4]{m} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=27mm]{example-image-duck}
            & \MakeUppercase{Name Goes Here} \\
```

than result of compilation of the MWE is

[image]

IN such cases it may be sensible to consider to use large fonts in table. In the first row `\Huge` and in the rows 2-4 `\large`, which can be set by the following options in table preamble:

```
               row{1} = {font=\Huge\bfseries, abovesep=5pt}, 
               row{2-Z} = {font=\large},
```

which fives the following result:

[image]

Comment: It may be considering that OP question deserve due to new possible solution presented in above answer, which is not contained in answers on the duplikate question, be reopen.

Comment: Yes actually, back in the day the question which is the original of this marked duplicate didn't answer my question completely. This is a better way of doing it